# How to query MySQL DATETIIME using UTC?

Tags: mysql, timezone

I have stored DATETIME values in MySQL8 which are all UTC. In my case that is -2h. The Ubuntu 20. Server runs on local time and there is a replica also running on local time.

While doing a cron job I realized that the query never returns results due to the time zone shift:

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE
WHERE
   r.FOUND >= NOW() - interval 1 minute
```

How can this query be altered to reflect UTC timezone? I am querying with Python but also within other environments (e.g. Grafana). Also the output should be in the timezone of the user.

Comment: *I have stored DATETIME values in MySQL8 which are all UTC.* The column of `DATETIME` datatype stores the value which is inserted without any zone shift. What you save is what is stored and is what you get. If you need to adjust stored value to definite timezone then apply [CONVERT_TZ() function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_convert-tz) with proper parameters explicitly.

Comment: Thank you that worked. I guess I need to convert all 100+ queries to use CONVERT_TZ(MY_CHANGED,'UTC','Europe/Berlin')